# bootstrap grid items are not rendering correctly

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using react-bootstrap for resposinve grid layout and material-ui for component. I want to show 3 items per row and my first row is working as expected but next row behaves abnormally. Why is that so? Here is my code

```
const Content = ({restaurant}) => {
  const restaura = _.map(restaurant, (restaurant) => {
    return(
      <Col xs={12} sm={12} md={4}>
        <div className="card">
            <div className="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
            <Link to={"restaurant/" + restaurant.slug}>  {restaurant.image ?
                              <img src={restaurant.image} alt={restaurant.name} className="activator responsive-img"/>
                              :<img className="activator" src="" />}
            </Link>
            </div>
            <div className="card-content">
            <Link to={"restaurant/" + restaurant.slug}><span className="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">{restaurant.name}</span></Link>
            </div>
        </div>
      </Col>
    );
  });
  return(
    <div className="container-fluid">
      <div className="row">
        <h3 className="flow-text">Collections</h3>
      </div>
        <div>
          <Grid>
            <Row className="restaura show-grid">
              {restaura}
            </Row>
          </Grid>
        </div>
      </div>
  );
}
```

Currently it looks like attached image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is being caused buy the images not being all the exact same dimensions. The varying height on the images is causing them not to clear within the row.

Notice, in the inspector if you give them all the same dimensions it will auto align.

You're going to need to make the col-XX-XX on them use something such as flexbox to equal the column heights or make the images parse to the same size.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use the bootstrap inbuilt **.clearfix** class for better support across all the browser. Put the following div block after every third block:

```
<div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
```

This is a common problem which is occur while creating layout using the Bootstrap column wrapping feature. Checkout this article to understand it better - http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-grid-system.php

Comment: Thanks for sharing knowledge. I will definitely look into it.